# How to prove order of element $o(a^k)=m$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $a ∈ G$ has a order $n=mk$ where $m, k\ge 1$
>
> prove that order of $a^k$ is $m$

---

My attempt:

Ok, it's clear that $$(a^k)^m = a^{mk} = a^n = e$$

Thus $o(a^k)\le m$ now how do I come up with that k is the **least**?

> Can you explain in formal way? Please.

Comment: Show that if the order is smaller, then so would the order of $a$ be.

Answer (score 0):

suppose not. then the order of a is strictly less than n, a contradiction